# How can i display the array in a page a format

Tags: php

I have to read  the following array generated from database and display  in a page .

**Array :result.php**

```
   Array
(
    [BC] => Array
        (
            [Regional Support Centre (Burnaby)] => Array
                (
                    [1] => position1
                )

        )

    [Prairies] => Array
        (
            [Winnipeg] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Position2
                )

        )

    [Ontario] => Array
        (
            [Regional Support Centre (Mississauga)] => Array
                (
                    [3] => position3
                )

            [Mississauga] => Array
                (
                    [4] => position4
                    [5] =>  position5
                    [6] =>  position6
                )

            [London] => Array
                (
                    [7] => Technician - Experienced Apprentices
                )
        )

)
```

**Expected output:**
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Can anyone please help me to how to read the array generated from the database and display it in the page .

Comment: Code would be a good starting point.

Comment: your question is both unclear and too broad.

Comment: You need a couple loops (and some sort of attempt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($myArray as $k => $v )
{
    echo '<li>'.$k.'</li>';
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($v as $k2 => $v2)
    {
        echo '<li>'.$k2.'</li>';
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($v2 as $v3)
        {
            echo '<li>'.$v3.'</li>';
        }   
        echo '</ul>';
    }   
    echo '</ul>';

}
echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
foreach($your_arr as $parent_cat => $sub_arr){
    echo $parent_cat.'<br>';

    if(is_array($sub_arr)){
        foreach($sub_arr as $cat => $items){
            echo '--'.$cat.'<br>';

            if(is_array($items)){
                foreach($items as $val){
                    echo '-----'.$val.'<br>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've created a tree structure but you can add your HTML in `echo` statement.